# Binary data structure for fast searching

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable, binary-tree

I'm looking for a binary data structure (tree, list) that enables very fast searching. I'll only add/remove items at the beginning/end of the program, all at once. So it's gonna be fixed-sized, thus I don't really care about the insertion/deletion speed. Basically what I'm looking for is a structure that provides fast searching and doesn't use much memory.

Thanks

Comment: What is the nature of your data? Could it be sorted? What is the size of it, and what are the memory constraints?

Comment: Haspemulator, it's around five pointers, and I guess it could be sorted because each piece of data has a unique pointer. It's gonna have many nodes, on average probably around 50.

Comment: @myrkos, so you need to search through 50 integers, or through 50 instances of structure with 5 pointers in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the Unordered set in the Boost C++ library [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/unordered.html).  Unlike red-black trees, which are O(log n) for searching, the unordered set is based on a hash, and on average gives you O(1) search performance.

Answer (score 4):

One container not to be overlooked is a sorted std::vector.

It definitely wins on the memory consumption, especially if you can reserve() the correct amount up front.

Comment: +1. Using `lower_bound` to find a element in a sorted vector essentially emulates the search behaviour of a `set`, but the `vector` is much more memory efficient, and thus the lookup will probably be much faster, too, because of memory locality.

Comment: Just make sure to do a binary search to find your data, and this is a good answer if you don't have to change the data at runtime, for a small (50ish) set.

Answer (score 2):

So the key can be a simple type and the value is a smallish structure of five pointers.

With only 50 elements it starts getting small enough that the Big-O theoretical performance may be overshadowed or at least measurable affected by the fixed time overhead of the algorithm or structure.

For example an array a vector with linear search is often the fastest with less than ten elements because of its simple structure and tight memory.

I would wrap the container and run real data on it with timing.  Start with STL's vector, go to the standard STL map, upgrade to unordered_map and maybe even try Google's dense or sparse_hash_map:
http://google-sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

One efficient (albeit a teeny bit confusing) algorithm is the [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Black_tree).

Internally, the c++ standard library uses Red-Black trees to implement `std::map` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-red-black-tree)

Answer (score 0):

The `std::map` and hash map are good choices.  They also have constructors to ease one time construction.

The hash map puts key data into a function that returns an array index.  This may be slower than an `std::map`, but only profiling will tell.

My preference would be `std::map`, as it is usually implemented as a type of binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest tends to be a trei/trie. I implemented one 3 to 15 times faster than the std::unordered_map, they tend to use more ram unless you use a large number of elements though.