# Dynamically allocating an array of objects fails

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, default-constructor

I'm able to create a dynamically sized array of integers like this:

```
int *cacheL2 = new int[L2/B2];
```

and I'm also able to create an object of type `Data` like this:

```
Data one(12,12);
```

and now I want a dynamically sized array of `Data`:

```
Data * vlaObj = new Data[L2/B2];
```

but it does not work...

Also, if you can tell me how to get hashes working for c++ that would be great. I was looking for examples, but everything just says #include "hash_map" however when I try to use the library it cant seem to find any of them.

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Comment: I suspect your class doesn't have a default constructor? Oh, and as for a hash map, if you can use C++11, use std::unordered_map.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the STL?

Comment: Why not use std::vector for the VLA and std::map for the hash?

Comment: @Adam27X: Note that `std::map` is not a hash table. You might want to read [Why is `std::map` implemented as red-black tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-red-black-tree)

Comment: pedantic point, what you are doing is called a [dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2672106/1520364) and not a  [Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the unordered map, Im going to try to use that instead!

Comment: @user2036351 Are you going to include a description of _what_ problems or errors you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

// ...
std::vector<Data> v;
v.emplace_back( 12, 12 );
```

Comment: Worth to note that `emplace_back` is C++11 feature. C++03 replacement could be `v.push_back(Data(12,12));`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to not use STL containers here. It is recommended to use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers:

```
#include <vector>

//...
std::vector<Data> vlaObj(L2/B2);
vlaObj.push_back(one)
```

Edit: BTW is there any chance that L2 or even B2 value can be `0`?

Comment: I suspect if OP's example "did not work", this one wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most probable reasons why `Data* arr = new Data[len];` wouldn't work is because type `Data` has no default constructor, i.e. `Data::Data()`.

But no matter whether `Data` has a default constructor or not, it's not a good idea to try to create an array like this anyway. Once you dynamically allocate it with `new[]` you commit yourself to take care of ugly memory management connect with it. It's much better idea to use one of STL containers such as `std::vector` (`#include <vector>` required) that will take care of memory management for you.

Then you have several options:

```
std::vector<Data> v;                    // option 1
v.reserve(len);
// in loop:
    v.push_back(Data(x, y));            // there could be different values

std::vector<Data> v2(len);              // option 2

std::vector<Data> v3(len, Data(12,12)); // option 3
```

First option will fit almost any situation. It prepares the chunk of memory big enough to hold `len` elements and then you can just fill `v` in convenient but still very efficient manner. Option 2 requires `Data` to have default constructor, which is solved by option 3 that uses your custom constructor to construct elements.

All mentioned options result in `std::vector` object with automatic storage duration being created. Note that all elements are stored in a continuous block of memory, so you can use `&v[0]` to initialize the pointer to its first element and work with it in a same way you would work with dynamically allocated array.