# How would you utilize a Binary search tree and a Map within the same program?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

the title is a question I was asked in class, supposedly there is an answer, I guess you could use the map to sort the data before putting it into the tree but that's all I can think of.

putting this out there in-case someone has any other solutions and can point me in the right direction, I'm stumped atm and my tutor isn't the best when it comes to answering questions

Comment: A map is usually just a red-black self-balancing binary search tree so I guess I don't understand the question either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468020/stdmap-and-binary-search-tree

Comment: It's like you are asking: How would you use a steering wheel and a car in the same movie?