# Searching an element by a key value in STL map

Tags: c++, search, dictionary, stl

Is it necessary to do a loop (with the related iterators) to search an element in a STL map? Or does it work with .find(key_value) STL method?

If I could do both ways I suppose that .find method it works more efficient, could you also confirm it?

For example:

1.Doing this by a loop:

```
map<string,User> mapUser;
map<string,User>::iterator it=mapUser.begin(); 
while(it != mapUser.end()){
  if(it->first == ID){
      //ID found
  }
  ++it;
}
```

2.Doing this by .find(key_value):

```
map<string,User> mapUser;
map<string,User>::iterator it=mapUser.find(ID); 
    if(it != mapUser.end()){   
          // ... ID found (there is a key value in STL map equal to ID)
    }else
          // ID not found
```

Comment: That's what maps are for dude.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is [implemented as a R-B Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree), so `find` is O(logN). There's no way to make this "more efficient". Searching by iteration is O(N) and incredibly inefficient, completely defeating the point of using a `std::map` in the first place.

I recommend you look up what a `std::map` is and how it compares to something like a `std::vector`.