# How to add element in std::map doing allocation oneself?

Tags: c++, dictionary

The purpose behind my question is to use `std::map` (ie insertion, deletion, access) with guarantee that no exception will throw from `std::map` implementation.

Deletion is not a problem, neither access if one use things carefully (no `at` without check for example).

But insertion is another problem. In this code:

```
#include <map>

struct foo{};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, foo> my_map;

  my_map.insert(std::pair<int, foo>(42, foo{}));
}
```

`my_map` do some allocation and throw if there is no more memory.

Now, what I want is a way to do this:

```
#include <map>

struct foo{};

int main()
{
  std::map<int, foo> my_map;
  auto my_new_pair{ new std::pair<int, foo>(42, foo{}) };

  if (my_new_pair) // ok, we could build the node
  {
    my_map.insert(my_new_pair); // no allocation, my_map only takes the "ownership" of my_new_pair
  }
}
```

but there is no such overload of `insert`.

Do you guys have a solution?

Comment: Give the map a custom allocator.  You can then make that allocator unexceptional ;).  You will have to work out what you want to have happen if you run out of memory though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The purpose behind my question is to use std::map (ie **insertion**,
>   deletion, access) **with guarantee** that no exception will throw from
>   std::map implementation.

If you leave the default `std::allocator` in place when instantiating a

*std::map`<`Key, T, Com=std::less`<`Key`>`, Allocator=**`std::allocator<...>`**`>`*;

then you cannot make any exception guarantees. in `inserts` or `emplace`.

> [23.2.1/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers#container.requirements.general-8):
>   Unless otherwise specified, all containers defined in this clause
>   obtain memory using an allocator

---

I don't see how its possible to do inserts without memory allocation in most STL implementations because [they mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree) make use of [Red Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) with heap allocated nodes. You may want to use a custom allocator that allocates from an existing memory pool, with noexcept guarantees. Or write your own container.

Comment: Your answer seems the closest of my need. In the custom allocator I test the return of `new` and abort the program if `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Use node extraction and transplanation:

```
{
    std::map<int, foo> staging_map;
    staging_map.emplace(42, foo{});

    real_map.insert(staging_map.extract(42));  // cannot throw
}
```

You're not quite doing the allocation "yourself", but you basically can get hold of a pre-allocated map node with this approach that you can use to your own ends until you're ready to insert it into the map, e.g.:

```
auto nh = staging_map.extract(42);
// Done initializing.

// use nh freely

real_map.insert(std::move(nh));  // guaranteed to work
```

Comment: Note that it is from C++17.

Comment: Can't `staging_map.emplace(42, foo{});` still throw an exception?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, so I think that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, sure, there's always *some* part where you allocate something and that can fail. The upshot is that we can move that point arbitrarily far away from the final insertion with an approach like this.

Comment: Okay.  Just wanted to check.  It will be nice when we can actually move the nodes.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sure il could fit for some cases, but in my case we do not have too much memory, and whatever the place, we do not want exceptions.

Comment: @Boiethios: Hm, your question shows use of `new` as an design goal. How does that square with not wanting exceptions?