# Internal storage of a std::map as a red-black tree

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree, red-black-tree

In this `map` example:

```
std::map<int, int> m; 
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    m[2*i] = i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)   // just an example of filling a map
    m[2*i + 1] = i;
```

**how to know how the internal "red-black tree" will look like?**

Which nodes will be a child of which other nodes?

Understanding this (visually) in such a simple example, would allow me to grasp better how the red-black tree map implementation work.

I read many answers such as [Why is std::map implemented as a red-black tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree) about implementation of `std::map` as a red-black tree, but it didn't help. I also read [Red–black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), but again, a simple example in the case of a map would help to understand how it works.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how the standard specifies `std::map`? Do you want to know how red-black trees work? Note either question  is ill-fitted for SO.

Comment: @PasserBy I want to know, with some C++ code, which node will be child of other nodes in the example given here (more precisely, in the underlying tree of the std::map structure).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know without digging into the internals of your vendor's `std::map` implementation. For instance, on vendor make `std::map<int` use tries rather than red-black trees.

The standard allows many different choices, and vendors do not agree on some single best choice.

Comment: I understand it's implementation-dependent, but isn't there a way to analyse *what has been done* by looking at the bytes near address `&m`?

Comment: @Basj, Whether one can determine such a thing depends on the implementation. If you want to test it out, you might have success by running your programming in a debugger and stepping into the methods on `std::map`.