# C Balanced Binary Tree vs C++ std::map perfomance

Tags: c++, c, tree, binary, stdmap

Having a discussion with some experienced developers about containers in C++, they told me that for better performance, instead of using std::map, they just use a classic C binary tree.
Since an std::map is implemented as a binary tree, is there a reason why a user implemented C style binary tree, can be faster than an std::map?

Comment: Did they back up their claims by actual performance measurements?

Comment: *Since an std::map is implemented as a binary tree* -- It is implemented *usually* as a [red-black tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/why-is-stdmap-implemented-as-a-red-black-tree)

Comment: Related video: [CppCon 2016: Dan Saks “extern c: Talking to C Programmers about C++”](https://youtu.be/D7Sd8A6_fYU).

Comment: Also "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I would never, ever trade a C++ class (especially a std class) for a C library without doing intensive performance measurements first. The answer "Use this, because it's faster." is a pretty dangerous claim. You want to use what's best for your use-case.    If your 'map' usage takes up only 0.5% of your CPU cycles at runtime, why bother replacing it with something else, especially if you throw away all the benefits you get from C++ and a std lib. (Also I don't think a classic C binary tree really is faster).

Comment: @Hajo Kirchhoff. They team is making a fully professional code and after tests, they end using for some purposes C trees instead of std::map, for a part of the code the really matters about the speed of the whole procedure.

Comment: @dkmg -- So what your programmers are doing is writing a "pure" binary tree class, and *not* a `std::map` clone, i.e. you're comparing apples to oranges.  In C++, there are *no* binary tree classes that are standard, thus even a C++ programmer would have to write their own binary tree implementation, as none exists in STL.

Answer (score 3):

One reason why `std::map` can be less efficient than some tree implementations in C is that it is not "intrusive."

An intrusive container is where bookkeeping information is stored directly in the values.  For example, a binary tree in C might be based on this type:

```
struct node {
    node *left, *right;
    int key;
    int value;
};
```

Whereas in C++ it would be:

```
std::map<int, int>
```

The difference is that when you insert a key/value pair into the C++ map, the map allocates memory to hold the node then copies the key/value pair into it.  In C, a node can be allocated once and then inserted into a tree without further allocation or copying.

[Boost Intrusive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) implements several intrusive containers in C++, with a main goal being performance parity with the "C style" data structures.  There is no `map`, but there is `boost::intrusive::set`, which can be used instead (by making the `value_type` hold both the key and the value from the map).

C++17 added [`std::map::insert(node_type&&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) which allows inserting a node without copying the key and value.  But the only way to obtain a `node_type` value is by using `std::map::extract(key)`.  You can't allocate a node outside of a container (with C or Boost Intrusive, you can).