# In map, key value pair does not stored in contagious memory ,so how iterator jump from one key value pair to another by using it++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  map<string, int> map1;

  map1["ank"] = 12;
  map1["ghan"] = 13;
  map<string, int>::iterator iter;

  for (iter = map1.begin(); iter != map1.end(); iter++)
  {
    cout << (*iter).first << " " << (*iter).second << endl;
    /* code */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

QUERY:

1. I want to ask, how just by using it++, it iterate through whole map, since they are not in contagious memory
2. Why not it work on it+1.

Comment: The `++` operator is [overloaded to perform custom iteration](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/69d5a6662115499198ebfa07a081e98a6ce4b915/libcxx/include/__tree#L842)

Answer (score 1):

The exact mechanism is left to the implementation, but most common implementations will use a pair of pointers alongside each key/value pair.

It's a pair of pointers so you can also call `it--`. But since you have only two pointers, you can't do `+3` or `+17`. And it's not really useful to have a `+N` that can only do `+1`

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is [commonly implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288320/) as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), where each node has pointers to some of the surrounding nodes.  A `map`'s iterator is simply implemented to iterate through that tree from one node to another by following those chains of pointers.